# Window function - N preceding and unbounded question

Tags: sql

Say I create a window function and specify:

```
ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

How does the window function treat the first 9 rows? Does it only calculate up to however many rows above it are available?

Comment: Your window frame specifies 11 rows.  I'm not sure why you are concerned about the first 9 rather than all 10 that precede the current row.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find this documented in SQL Server's documentation but I could find it in [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS), and I believe it is standardised<sup>1</sup>:

> In any case, the distance to the end of the frame is limited by the distance to the end of the partition, so that *for rows near the partition ends the frame might contain fewer rows than elsewhere.*

(My *emphasis*)

---

<sup>1</sup>Have also search MySQL documentation to no avail; This Q is just tagged [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) so should be based on the standard but I can't find any downloadable drafts of those at the moment either.

Comment: . . This. is standard behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It does the computation ,considering the 10 rows prior to the current row and the current row ,for the given partition window .For example if you want to sum up a number based on the last 3 years and current year ,you can do sum(amount) over (order by year asc) rows between 3 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW.

To answer your question "Does it only calculate up to however many rows above it are available?"  - Yes it considers only those rows which are available

Comment: Because this answer has nothing to do with the question? The question asks what is going to happen when the window specifies `BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING`, but there is only 5 preceding rows. This question is a rather poor attempt on explaining what `preceding` does in principle.

Comment: Well ,the question says "How does the window function treat the first 9 rows?" ,not sure about the only 5 preseding rows. Yes you are right in saying I didn't answer his second question. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Because the first 9 rows are the ones that don't have enough rows in front of them, given the window `BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. The first row has 0 in front, which is less than 10. The second row has 1 in front, which is less than 10. So the OP is asking what is going to happen to these 9 rows each of which does not have enough rows in front of it. In [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68281663/window-function-n-preceding-and-unbounded-question/68282282?noredirect=1#comment120682593_68282282), row number 6 would only have 5 rows in front of it.

Comment: In that case only the rows which are available will be considered for computation, that's the behavior when I tested it at my end. Anyways thank you for making the question clear ,I missed some points while answering for the first time.